# C# Regex to replace all anchor tags not including certain href

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace all anchor links inside html string not including certain href patterns.
For this example assume i want to remove all anchors who has href which is not www.a.com (which means all anchor tags with www.a.com/... won't be removed).

Consider the next html and output I'm trying to achieve

```
string html = "some text <a href=\"http://www.a.com\">Link1</a> some longer text <a href=\"http://www.b.com\">Link2</a> text";
string result = Regex.Replace(html, ??, ??, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string expectedOutput = "some text <a href=\"http://www.a.com\">Link1</a> some longer text Link2 text"
```

**In that case note that i would like to keep the text of the anchor "Link2"**

Im trying to accomplish this by Regex but unmanage to make it work.

Could you please tell me what regex should I use?

Comment: "but unmanage to make it work." is not a question.

Comment: I have implicity added now the question, though i find it quite obvious what's the question in my post.

Comment: [regex's are not a good solution for parsing html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Please consider an html parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Regex r = new Regex("(<a [ a-zA-Z0-9]?href=\"http://www.[a-zA-Z0-9]+.com\"[ a-zA-Z0-9]?>+)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)</a>");

    Match mh = r.Match(html);

    Dictionary<string, string> lst = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    while(mh.Success)
     {
      lst.Add(mh.Value, mh.Groups[2].Value);
      mh = mh.NextMatch();
     }

    foreach(var l in lst.Keys)
     {
      if(!l.Contains("http://www.a.com"))
       {
        html = html.Replace(l,lst[l]);
       }                
     }
```

Demo [here](http://rextester.com/RVL5470).

Note that this particular solution does match your expected output, but as pointed out in the comments, it would be better to use an HTML parser.

Comment: Thank you but as i see it l.Contains won't gurantee a perfect match with anchors who has more attributes.. such has "target=" and so on, correct me if im wrong

Comment: Also, the regex itself is not quite accurate, due to same reason

Comment: Exactly. Which is why both my answer and the comments suggest that you use HTML parsers for HTML specific problems.

Comment: I have updated my answer to account for your points.

Comment: Thats great! meanwhile i did some trick which is keeping <a> tags with href that is recognized to me that should be replaced. for example: <a href="replace me"/>some text</a> what is missing is removing the anchor (like striping it) and replacing that with the 'somet text' instead. if u could provide extra solution it will be great too :)